# Cannot access the cmd through new admin account

Tags: cmd, admin

I made an admin account using the following command on the cmd:

```
net localgroup administrators [username] /add
```

But now whenever I try to access the cmd it says that either the file has not been found or I don't have permission to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

could you clarify?

Are you:

1) Saying you can't run cmd.exe after logging in as a new user?
  (IF so, that sounds like an issue for serverfault)

2) saying that you can't add the User you already created to the local group from the CMD?
  (If so, have you Tried right clicking and running the CMD as an administrator?)

3) Saying you are trying to create a user and add it using only this one command?

(If so, you cannot do this.  You Must create a user first before you can add it to a group.  to create a user at the CMD Prompt, you can use the "Net User" Command such as this:

```
NET USER [UserName] [password] /ADD
NET Localgroup [GroupName] [UserName] /ADD
```

e.g. Assuming the user you want to add is named "Joe", and you want the password to be "Abcd1234!" you would use the following:

```
NET USER Joe Abcd1234! /ADD
NET Localgroup Administrators Joe /ADD
```

)

4) Some other option?

If one through three the above responses should help.

Comment: Option number 1

Comment: then bring the question to server fault.  If you have created a user then logged in as them, and they can;t access cmd.exe there could be any one of a dozen reasons why; most likely it was removed by administrators of the system to prevent users from messing with it.

Comment: may i just say that this is a home computer

Comment: It's probably a bad profile could still be a dozen things.  Try Serverfault or bring it to geek squad, I'm too many years removed from desktop support to be very helpful to solving this problem.